# Fixing JSON with falsely stringified fields, including array fields

Tags: json

I have a JSON file containing fields which are falsely serialized as strings, like `numberfield` in this example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Entrygroup",
    "numberfield": "1",
    "arrayfield": "['Entry A', 'Entry B', 'Named Entry \"Somename\"', \\'Named Entry 'something else\\'']"
  }
]
```

While `numberfield` should be easy enough to fix with regex search and replace or a very simple script which parses arrayfields as as array and then replaces the value, but I do fear I would get the encoding of `arrayfield` wrong, as it is a stringified array using singlequotes as inner string delimiter and it could possibly use single- and doublequotes in the string array entries.

The JSON File is almost 1GB large, most online tools cannot handle this.
If you know a binary, I am currently using a Windows 11 System.

I tried to find tools that can do this, but only found webservices like [ableconvert.com](https://tableconvert.com/) which crash with a 1GB JSON File, and can only fix the `numberfield`, not `arrayfield`.

What I expect as the result is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Entrygroup",
    "numberfield": 1,
    "arrayfield": [
        "Entry A",
        "Entry B",
        "Named Entry \"Somename\"",
        "Named Entry 'something else'"
    ]
  }
]
```